# java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, t-sql, primary-key

I am trying to insert data into `arrivaltimes` tables but I am getting the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

```
stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops"
            + "(stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "
            + " name varchar(30) NOT NULL, "
            + " route INT(11) NOT NULL, "
            + " lat double(10,6) NOT NULL, "
            + " longi double(10,6)NOT NULL) " );

    stt.execute("INSERT INTO stops(name, route, lat, longi) values"
            + "('blabla', '1', '93.838039', '15.700440' ),"
            + "('backery', '9', '98.868863', '19.665438' )" );

    stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS arrivaltimes(id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
            +  " weekday VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,"
            + "arrivaltime time NOT NULL,"
            + " stop_id INT, FOREIGN KEY fk_stop_id(stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id) )" );
    //The error appears in this execution statement.
    stt.execute("INSERT INTO arrivaltimes(weekday, arrivaltime) values"
            + "('mon-fri', '05:30' ),"
            + "('mon-fri', '06:07' )" );
```

Comment: Your column id in the arrivaltimes table is your primary key, make sure you are inserting some value against this column

Comment: You probably want to make id auto_increment in the arrivaltimes table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `AUTO INCREMENT` for Primary Key in arrivaltimes table. Just need to add `AUTO_INCREMENT`  while creating table

```
stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS arrivaltimes(id INT(11) NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
            +  " weekday VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,"
            + "arrivaltime time NOT NULL,"
            + " stop_id INT, FOREIGN KEY fk_stop_id(stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id) )" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the column `id` is defined as `NOT NULL` which means it has to have a value and you're not providing one.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with my table in MySQL WorkBench.  Clearly, it is the auto increment command that is giving the Field 'id' a default value.  Here is the code that worked for my table:

```
create table product( <br>
id int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, <br>
name varchar(20), <br>
description varchar(100), <br>
price decimal(8,3) <br>
);
```