# SQLException: Field doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, save, auto-increment

I have a Skill entity with the following attributes;

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idskill", nullable = false) 
    private int idskill;

    private String skillName;
```

I want the Id to be assigned a random value, ideally auto incremented, when a new entry is created. 
I then attempt to save a new entry into an mysql database in a method;

```
Optional<Skill> skill=skillRepository.findByskillName(skillName);
        int id=0;
        if(skill.isPresent()) {
            id=Integer.valueOf(skill.get().getIdSkill());
        }
        else {
            Skill newSkill = new Skill();
            newSkill.setSkillName(skillName);
            skillRepository.save(newSkill);
        }
```

However, I am receiving this error;

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'idskill' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3106) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3699) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:702) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:688) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:368) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:554) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at main.CSVController.findSkill(CSVController.java:128) ~[classes/:na]
    at main.CSVController.importRoles(CSVController.java:109) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
```

Does anyone know why this would be? I don't want to have to alter my database from sql workbench if I don't have to. I was wondering if I was missing a default value attribute but I can't seem to find anything online

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133548/java-sql-sqlexception-field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you specified the column as not nullable, so hibernate will reject your operation if the id-field is not filled explicitly.

Change it as follows should fix the problem. GenerationType.AUTO will let the database take care of the id generation.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "idskill") 
private int idskill;
```

Comment: I've implemented this but I now receive this error; java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'. I have some entries already in the table, but I want it to be able to add them at any point regardless of entries already exisiting

Comment: If so, just check for highest id and follow accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-and-auto-increment-in-mysql

Comment: is there no way to set it to auto increment from the highest value in the table? this method seems like adding a lot of unnecessary querying

Comment: What is complicated about ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT=your_value; ?